# Binding to ReactiveUserControl.ViewModel does not set the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I created `ReactiveUserControl<Item>`. It works well with ViewModelViewHost and so on.

I figured that I could use it on it's own in XAML like this:

```
<local:ItemView ViewModel="{Binding SelectedBigItem.Item}"/>
```

but it does not work - SelectedBigItem.Item is not displayed. The property SelectedBigItem does raise change notifications. Item itself is DTO - just plain properties.

I know two solutions:

1. Use ViewModelViewHost - seems like a huge overkill, since it will always display the same view
2. code behind subscription. I gave the control name = "ItemPreview" and in CB:

   ```
           IDisposable sub = null;
           sub = this.WhenActivated(d =>
           {
               ViewModel.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SelectedBigItem).Subscribe(quote =>
               {
                   ItemPreview.ViewModel = quote?.Item;
               }).DisposeWith(d);

               sub.DisposeWith(d);
           });
   ```

both work and I hate both: one is an overkill, and second feels like cheating and is tedious. Why binding does not work? I tried setting different triggers and modes, but nothing helped.

EDIT:

https://github.com/qrzychu/ReactiveUserControlBindingSample

I craeted quick sample. There are 3 ways of binding and the only one that does not work is through ViewModel.SelectedItem property.

```
<!--        Works-->
        <local:ItemView DockPanel.Dock="Top" ViewModel="{Binding ElementName=List, Path=SelectedItem}"/> 
<!--        Does not work-->
        <local:ItemView DockPanel.Dock="Top" ViewModel="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>

<!--        Set in MainWindow.xaml.cs. Works-->
        <local:ItemView DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="ItemView"/>
```

In the first commit you can see that it behaves exactly the same when there is no BigItem and just Item

Comment: Can you share it in a repo to take a look ?

Comment: @AdriánRomero see my edit